# Change text with different text on click

Tags: javascript, text, onclick

Let me preface my question with my limited understanding of web design.

I would like for the "-More-" text to become "-Less-" when clicked, then back to "-More-" when clicked again.

I already have some javascript present within the code I am trying to modify. Could this be combined with what I am asking to achieve the same result?

My javascript as follows:

```
function showHide(shID) {
  if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
    if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
        document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

My html as follows:

```
  <div class="accordion">
    <p>1. Decide
    <a href="#" id="exampleone-show" class="showLink"
    onclick="showHide('exampleone');return false;"><div class="btn_show">-More-</div></a>
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div id="exampleone" class="more">
    <p>Blah Blah Blah.</p>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you use [jQuery](http://jQuery.com)?

Comment: @PraveenKumar It seems so but as I stated in my initial post, that is not something I am capable of doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is not necessary to perform this function, and it will simply make the whole script more cumbersome and slow. Simply use this pure JavaScript solution:

```
function showHide(i) {
if (document.getElementById("example"+i).innerHTML=="-More-") {
    document.getElementById("example"+i).innerHTML="-Less-";
    document.getElementById("more"+i).style.display = 'block';
}
else if (document.getElementById("example"+i).innerHTML=="-Less-"){
    document.getElementById("example"+i).innerHTML="-More-";
    document.getElementById("more"+i).style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

This code uses `i` as a parameter defining what link/`div` needs to be changed.
For your HTML, use this:

```
<div class="accordion">
<p>1. Decide</p>
    <a href="#" id="**example1**" class="showLink" onclick="**showHide(1)**">-More-</a>
</div>
<div id="**more1**" class="more" style="display:none;">
    <p>Blah Blah Blah.</p>
</div>
```

Basically, you can keep on copying this HTML code multiple times for as many times you need. Just makes sure you change the parts of the code in double asterisks. (The JavaScript code works by identifying ids like `example1` and `example2`; by passing this number into `showHide()`, the code can be used for multiple instances.)

Here's a JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/3Xawv/

Comment: Thanks for your response however this also does not seem to work

Comment: Hmm....Works for me. Check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NkHvB/5/). If you are using JSFiddle to test, make sure you specify "no wrap (head)" or "no wrap (body)", as event handlers do not work well in JSFiddle otherwise.

Comment: It sure does...I pasted in your exact code last night and it wouldn't work. Thanks for your help Bagavatu!

Comment: One more quick question, as I failed to relay this in my initial post...I have multiple instances of the html (ie: a #2, a #3, and so on) The "more" and "less" function works properly with a single instance but not multiple. What needs to be done to modify your code to accommodate this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would probably want to make a set of ids like this for your divs: `example1`, `example2`, `example3`, etc. I'll go ahead and update the reply so it can be used for multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is to use jQuery, however you could do something like this, passing the click event in like so:

```
 <a href="#" id="exampleone-show" class="showLink"
onclick="showHide('exampleone', event);return false;">
```

And then on the JS side

```
function showHide(shID, e) {
    if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
        if (document.getElementById(shID + '-show').style.display != 'none') {
            document.getElementById(shID + '-show').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(shID + '-show').style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
    target = e.target;
    element = target.getElementsByClassName('btn_show');
    html = element.innerHTML;
    element.innerHTML = "";
    if (html.indexOf("-More-") != -1) {
        element.innerHTML = "-Less-";
    } else if (html.indexOf("-Less-") != -1) {
        element.innerHTML = "-More-";
    }
}​
```

Clarifications: e.target will return the element that actually received the click event - in this case a link.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response however when I paste your code into my document I receive a syntax error on the line:  else if...

Comment: There was a missing brace before the else. Should be fixed now

Comment: my apologies, I thought the div was a sibling of the link, while it was actually nested within. Also, MORE and LESS aren't upper case.

Comment: Now, when I click "-More-" nothing happens.